# Minimist not finding arguments

Tags: gulp

I am trying to use minimist with gulp like this...

```
  var minimist = require('minimist'),
  ...
  knownOptions = {
    string: ['env'],
    boolean: ['watch'],
    default: {
      env: process.env.NODE_ENV || '',
      watch: false
    }
  },
  options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), knownOptions),
  install = require("gulp-install");

  console.log("The options are "+process.argv.slice(2));
  console.log("The watch is "+options.watch);
```

but when I run `gulp clean -watch true` I still see...

> The options are clean,-watch,true
>
> The watch is false

Why is it still false?

**UPDATE**

this works `gulp clean --watch true` but can't I do it with 1 slash instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (and tested) that since you are invoking the gulp cli, the flags are parsed from gulp itself which stops the execution and prompts you to the "Usage" cli manual.

Just for the record, all of the following will evaluate watch=true:
`gulp clean --watch true
gulp clean --watch
gulp clean --watch=true`